# Laravel: search and filter data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-controller

**i want to multi filter data in laravel but i show this error:**

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()
```

**Please help me to solve this issue.**

```
public function searchLanding(Request $request)
{

    $landings = Landing::all();

    if(count($landings) && !is_null($request->title)) {
        $landings = $landings->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$request->title}%")->get();
    }

    if (count($landings) && !is_null($request->start_at)) {
        $landings = $landings->where('start_at', '>=', $request->start_at)->get();
    }

    if (count($landings) && !is_null($request->end_at)) {
        $landings = $landings->where('end_at', '<=', $request->end_at)->get();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function searchLanding(Request $request)
{

    $landings = Landing::query();

    if(!is_null($request->title)) {
        $landings->orWhere("name", "LIKE", "%{$request->title}%");
    }

    if (!is_null($request->start_at)) {
        $landings->orWhere('start_at', '>=', $request->start_at);
    }

    if (!is_null($request->end_at)) {
        $landings->orWhere('end_at', '<=', $request->end_at);
    }

     return $landings->get();
}
```

Note:
You shouldn't call `all()` or `get()` when you are still building your query, only call them when you want to get the result.

Use `where()` when you want all conditions to be true,
or use `orWhere()` when you want one of the conditions to be true.

In the example above, only one of the conditions needs to be true e.g. search found in `title` or after `start_at` or before `end_at`.